# How do I use i3wm long with all gnome and ubuntu default software?

Tags: gnome, ssh, git, 23.04, i3-wm

I'm currently trying out i3wm on my Ubuntu system (Ubuntu 23.04), but am having some difficulties. I like the window manager, and I like the easily customizable config file, but I'm having a lot of trouble with stuff like software and settings.

*Disclaimer: I'm a relative noobie with regards to distros, and don't have the time to invest hours upon end to troubleshoot my PC. If what I'm asking for is impossible, then so be it, and I'll stay on default Ubuntu.*

The main issues I'm having are:

- I don't have an SSH keyring anymore. I found very little information on how to fix this. Applications like vs-code do not detect my SSH keys automatically anymore, making it impossible to use the GUI for git interfacing.
- Gnome settings don't work anymore, and the GUI also looks much worse than in default Ubuntu.

For the ssh keyring, I tried starting a daemon, but I'm not exactly sure what that is or how it works. It didn't fix the issue for me, and the only way I could actually use my SSH keys with Git was by opening a terminal, starting an agent in that terminal, and then using Git. Normal SSH tunneling worked fine though, with vs-code remote SSH working very well.

**My main question is:** is there a way to use i3wm with all the default ubuntu/gnome software in the background? (Nautilus, Gnome settings, Gnome keyring, etc...). If possible, also with good looking GUI, but otherwise anything that works is fine.

Thank you very much, and sorry if this is badly asked or if I'm missing something.